# How to reference a previously calculated row in pandas without looping?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Data:

```
    day    cost    new_column
    1       1        0
    2       1        0
    3       5        enter position
    4       3        stay in position
    5       10       stay in position
    6       1        exit position
    7       1        0
```

Hi, I'm wondering if there is a way to reference a previous row in a calculated column without looping and using loc/iloc. In the above example, I want to calculate this 'new_column'. Once the cost hits 5, I want to enter the position. Once I am in a position, I want to be able to check on the next line if I am already in a position and check that the price is not 1. If so then I stay in the position. The first row I hit where the cost is 1 and the previous "new_column" is 'stay in position' I want to make 'exit position'. Then the next row with 1, 'new_column' should go back to zero.

How I am solving this now is by looping over each row, looking at the cost on row i and the status of new_column on row i-1, then inserting the result in new_column on row i.

This takes a while on large data sets and I would like to find a more efficient way to do things. I looked into list(map()), but i don't see a way to reference a previous row, because I don't think that data will have been created yet to reference. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at `.shift()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: I don't think I could use shift in this case because I can't reference new_column[-1]. So for example, If i want to populate day 4, new_column, I need to look at day 3 new_column and cost. I don't know how to reference day 3 new_column without looping

Comment: @nickm. It will be always a loop. But if you loop using np.where, it will be faster than loc or iterrows. If you use np.where you will use all power from C

Answer (score 2):

Hey as smj suggested one option is using shift.

```
day = list(range(1,8))
cost = [1,1,5,3,10,1,1]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'day':day,'cost':cost}, columns = ['day', 'cost'])
print(df)
df['new'] = np.where(df['cost']> 1, np.where(
                                             df['cost'].shift(-1) >=1,
                                             'stay','a'
                                            ),
                     np.where(
                              df['cost'].shift()>1, 'exit', 0
                             )
                    )
print(df)
```